# textjoin if the next Column is repeated

Tags: countif, textjoin

I have a sheet to follow the shipments , and next to each shipment code write a comment about what happened, sometimes the shipments repeat and go to search for the comment that I wrote to copy , I want an equation as soon as this code is repeated, the comment is automatically written in the comment box, the box where the codes are F and the box where the comment is J

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F$2:$F,F$2)>1,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(F$2:$F=F2,J$2:$J,"")),"")
but it write all in the column J
```